# Is it possible to keep parameters in doxygen HTML output on one line?

Tags: doxygen

In the HTML output doxygen generates, the parameters of a method are put on extra lines if there is more than one parameter so it looks like this:

```
Functions

void function0 ()
void function1 (int para1)
void function2 (int para1, int para2)
void function3 (int para1, int para2, int para3)


Function Documentation

void function0 ( )

void function1 ( int para1 )

void function2 ( int para1,
                 int para2 
               )

void function3 ( int para1,
                 int para2,
                 int para3 
                )
```

Is it possible to do a configure/CSS/whatever so that the documentation part looks like the function list?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, or does anyone else have the answer?

Comment: @TimBeaudet Just added a pretty simple solution

Answer (score 5):

I've just managed to do this fairly simply on `Doxygen 1.8.10`. The solution is to create a new CSS file (e.g `inline_params.css`) and include the following very short snippet:

```
table.memname tr {
    float: left;
}
```

Place this somewhere logical (beside your project's `Doxyfile`) and under the `Expert` table of the Doxywizard you should select "HTML" and find the `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` setting. Browse to your `css`, add it to the list and save your settings. When you run Doxygen your output should be like this:

[image]

EDIT: BTW, I've a wee little [github project](https://github.com/Diom/doxy-flat) which includes this CSS file, so you can grab it there if you really want!