# How to change Doxygen macro / function arguments formatting?

Tags: doxygen

I want to change Doxygen macros and function arguments formatting. Whatever this formatting is trying to achieve can be done with `@param`, which will describe function parameters way better in the section down below. Also, explicitly saying `void` as function arguments formats it with some strange spacing, while right above it Doxygen understood that `nop(void)` is equal to `nop()`, which just drives me crazy.

[image]

[image]

I think that macro / function arguments formatting should be a configurable option. I want to change mine formatting from multiline to one line, since I don't see the benefits of doing otherwise.

```
#define ADD(a, b) a + b
int add(int a, int b)
```

I couldn't find anything about function arguments formatting. About `void` people said to use aliases, but gave no examples, so I am stuck here. Hope I gave enough info on what I am trying to achieve!

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? The multiline arguments is useful when having long argumnt names / argument types (templated types etc.).

Comment: @albert, Understandable, but I am not dealing with 8 argument functions or any other big constructs of C++ language. My Doxygen version is 1.9.6

Comment: Possible solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34597356/2041317